# How to extract combinations from Orders in Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet, see screenshot below for a snapshot, containing a large number of Order Numbers and the associated SKUs that were within those orders.

I'm looking for a way to extract what combinations of SKUs are being ordered together. This is furniture, so for example what chairs with what tables, to find what our most popular combinations are.

I'm not a total beginner to Excel, but neither am I any kind of wizard with it.

I'm hoping to be pointed in the right direction for this.

I think I kind of know one way to approach it, but it would involve learning Python and probably wouldn't be very elegant. My hope is that there's something built into Excel already that can do this.

[image: Screenshot from Spreadsheet, showing how data is laid out with order number, SKUs, and quantities]

Comment: Can you export your orders, so that every order is in a single row? The current setup makes it trickier since it seems that some rows might be the order number and other rows might be the articles within that order number.

Comment: @Loeli You make a very good point. I'm not sure. I certainly can't export them straight out like that, our system isn't very good at data exporting. The spreadsheet is currently a pivot table, so I believe the Order Numbers and SKUs are treated differently somehow (I can close/expand each order) - but I'm not super familiar with how that works exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that there is some sort of established coding approach for this task but I honestly don't it. If I'd have to do it in Excel, I would do it the following way:

1. List all orders in a single row and make sure that the articles are sorted withing that row (in this example, they are sorted alphabetically). You will need one column for the order number and then as many columns as your largest order has articles (e.g. if you largest order contains 10 different articles, list them all next to each other).

[image]

2. Click into this data cluster, go to the "Insert" tab, click on "PivotTable" and confirm with "OK"

[image]

3. In the Pivot Table Fields selector drag all the article columns into the "Rows" field. Drag the order number column into the "Values" field.

[image]

4. Now you can evaluate the data. In my example you can see that the article "Apple" has been sold the most and it most often went together with "Banana" and then "Grapes"

[image]

Keep in mind, that this approach only works if the articles within a single row are properly sorted! And also, you won't be able to sum up subsets with this. You can see that order 1 for example has the subset (Banana | Grape) and order 4 also has this set. But since they will not be within the same group in the pivot table, you will not realize that you have more of this subset than what is shown.

I know this is not the most elegant approach, but it is definitely an easy one which doesn't require you to code.